# One comment per user per post

Tags: forms, comments

How can i disable the comment form, if the user is already submitted a comment for the specified post?

I am using this now, but this is only good for 1 post / user / website.

```
<?php
global $current_user;
$args = array('user_id' => $current_user->ID);
$usercomment = get_comments($args);
if(count($usercomment) >= 1){
    echo 'disabled';
} else {
    comment_form();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply add the post_id parameter to the `get_comments` arguments array something like:

```
global $current_user,$post;
$args = array('user_id' => $current_user->ID,'post_id' => $post->ID);
$usercomment = get_comments($args);
if(count($usercomment) >= 1){
    echo 'disabled';
} else {
    comment_form();
}
```

Comment: What about limiting a register user to one comment per post and also 10 comments per entire website? Thanks

Comment: Ask that as a question